# facebook og tags on ipad/safari

Tags: ios, facebook, ipad, tags

I have og tags on my web page that plays video in place on desktop browsers. However, only on ipad/safari combination, when I click on liked video, it tries to invoke Flash player and reports error "Flash Player upgrade required". This doesn't happen on Facebook app or on iphone (instead opens a new window to the URL).

Here's my meta tags...

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Example">
<meta property="fb:admins" content="XXXXXX" />
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:title" content="Example Page">
<meta property="og:description" content="Example Description">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://URL">
<meta property="og:image" content="JPG URL" >
<meta property="og:video" content="Flash Player URL" >
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="SSL version of the Flash Player URL" >
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

I don't have SSL version of mp4, so I am ok to just go the website on iOS. I tried just putting

```
<meta property="og:video" content="http://mp4 URL">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4">
```

and it breaks my in-place even on my desktop.